# CS Mines Flood Fill problem - Java solution times out while Cpp and python succeeds (Performance improvement)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, hashset, treeset

Working to solve this problem

https://mines20.kattis.com/problems/mines20.paintbucket

Java solution using TreeSet times out with time limit of less than 3 seconds

```
public class PaintBucketCSMinesSolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // maintain distinct list of points that have been visited
        Set<int[]> exploredSet = new TreeSet<>(
                Comparator.comparingInt((int[] el) -> el[1]).thenComparingInt(el -> el[0]));
        int W;
        int H;
        int X;
        int Y;
        int[][] picture;
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(r.readLine());
        W = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        H = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        X = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        Y = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        picture = new int[H][W];
        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(r.readLine());
            for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                picture[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            }
        }

        int color = picture[Y][X];

        Stack<int[]> toExploreStack = new Stack<>();

        toExploreStack.add(new int[] { X, Y });

        while (!toExploreStack.isEmpty()) {
            int[] point = toExploreStack.pop();
            int px = point[0];
            int py = point[1];
            // System.out.println(exploredSet.contains(point));
            boolean execute = true;

            if (exploredSet.contains(point)) {
                execute = false;
            }

            if (execute) {
                exploredSet.add(point);

                if (px > 0 && picture[py][px - 1] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(new int[] { px - 1, py });
                }

                if (px < (W - 1) && picture[py][px + 1] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(new int[] { px + 1, py });
                }

                if (py > 0 && picture[py - 1][px] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(new int[] { px, py - 1 });
                }

                if (py < (H - 1) && picture[py + 1][px] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(new int[] { px, py + 1 });
                }
            }

        }
        // exploredSet.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((int[] el) ->
        // el[1]).thenComparingInt(el -> el[0]));
        // Sorting HashSet using List

        for (int[] v : exploredSet) {
            System.out.println(v[0] + " " + v[1]);
        }

    }
}
```

**Java HashSet** solution, which also times out

```
package datastructures.algorithms;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class PaintBucketCSMinesSolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // maintain distinct list of points that have been visited
//      Set<int[]> exploredSet = new TreeSet<>(
//              Comparator.comparingInt((int[] el) -> el[1]).thenComparingInt(el -> el[0]));
        Set<List<Integer>> exploredSet = new HashSet<>();
        int W;
        int H;
        int X;
        int Y;
        int[][] picture;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        W = sc.nextInt();
        H = sc.nextInt();
        X = sc.nextInt();
        Y = sc.nextInt();
        picture = new int[H][W];
        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                picture[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        int color = picture[Y][X];

        ArrayDeque<List<Integer>> toExploreStack = new ArrayDeque<>();

        toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(X, Y));

        while (!toExploreStack.isEmpty()) {
            List<Integer> point = toExploreStack.pop();
            int px = point.get(0);
            int py = point.get(1);
            // System.out.println(exploredSet.contains(point));
            boolean execute = true;

            if (exploredSet.contains(point)) {
                execute = false;
            }

            if (execute) {
                exploredSet.add(point);

                if (px > 0 && picture[py][px - 1] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px - 1, py));
                }

                if (px < (W - 1) && picture[py][px + 1] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px + 1, py));
                }

                if (py > 0 && picture[py - 1][px] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px, py - 1));
                }

                if (py < (H - 1) && picture[py + 1][px] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px, py + 1));
                }
            }

        }

        // Sorting HashSet using List

        // exploredSet.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((List<Integer> el) ->
        // el.get(1)).thenComparingInt(el -> el.get(0)));
        Comparator<List<Integer>> comp = Comparator.comparingInt((List<Integer> x) -> x.get(1))
                .thenComparingInt(x -> x.get(0));
        exploredSet.stream().sorted(comp).map(v -> v.get(0) + " " + v.get(1)).forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

**Java HashSet String** solution also timed out

```
package datastructures.algorithms;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class PaintBucketStringSolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // maintain distinct list of points that have been visited
//      Set<int[]> exploredSet = new TreeSet<>(
//              Comparator.comparingInt((int[] el) -> el[1]).thenComparingInt(el -> el[0]));
        Set<String> exploredSet = new HashSet<>();
        int W;
        int H;
        int X;
        int Y;
        int[][] picture;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        W = sc.nextInt();
        H = sc.nextInt();
        X = sc.nextInt();
        Y = sc.nextInt();
        picture = new int[H][W];
        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                picture[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        int color = picture[Y][X];

        ArrayDeque<List<Integer>> toExploreStack = new ArrayDeque<>();

        toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(X, Y));

        while (!toExploreStack.isEmpty()) {
            List<Integer> point = toExploreStack.pop();

            int px = point.get(0);
            int py = point.get(1);
            // String.valueOf(
            String pointString = String.valueOf(px) + " " + String.valueOf(py);
            // System.out.println(exploredSet.contains(point));
            boolean execute = true;

            if (exploredSet.contains(pointString)) {
                execute = false;
            }

            if (execute) {
                exploredSet.add(pointString);

                if (px > 0 && picture[py][px - 1] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px - 1, py));
                }

                if (px < (W - 1) && picture[py][px + 1] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px + 1, py));
                }

                if (py > 0 && picture[py - 1][px] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px, py - 1));
                }

                if (py < (H - 1) && picture[py + 1][px] == color) {
                    toExploreStack.add(Arrays.asList(px, py + 1));
                }
            }

        }

        // Sorting HashSet using List

        exploredSet.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> {
            String[] s = x.split(" ");
            return s[1] + " " + s[0];
        })).forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

**While solution in python succeeds for all test cases in 2.65 seconds**

```
W, H,X,Y = map(int, input().split())

picture=[]

for y in range(H):
    picture.append([int(c) for c in input().split()])

#print(picture)
# implement a stack
to_explore = [(X , Y)]
explored=set()
color = picture[Y][X]
#print("color" , color)

while len(to_explore) >0:
    px, py = to_explore.pop()

    if(px, py) in explored:
        continue
    explored.add((px, py))

    if (px > 0 and picture[py][px - 1] == color) :
       to_explore.append( (px - 1, py ))

    if (px < (W - 1) and picture[py][px + 1] == color) :
        to_explore.append((px + 1, py ))


    if (py > 0 and picture[py - 1][px] == color) :
        to_explore.append( (px, py - 1) )

    if (py < (H - 1) and picture[py + 1][px] == color) :
        to_explore.append(( px, py + 1) )
        
for x,y in sorted(explored, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])):
    print(x, y)
```

**CPP solution finishes in 2.05 seconds**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // comparison to sort the set naturally on inserting elements
    const auto compare = [](const std::array<int, 2> &lhs,
                            const std::array<int, 2> &rhs) {
        return lhs[1] < rhs[1] || (lhs[1] == rhs[1] && lhs[0] < rhs[0]);
    };

    // set to maintain unique elements as it is used for lookup to check if we have visited the node already
    std::set<std::array<int, 2>, decltype(compare)> exploredSet(compare);
    // std::set<std::array<int, 2>> exploredSet;
    int W;
    int H;
    int X;
    int Y;
    // std::vector<std::vector<int>> picture;
    std::cin >> W;
    std::cin >> H;
    std::cin >> X;
    std::cin >> Y;
    int picture[W][H];
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
            std::cin >> picture[i][j];
        }
    }
    int color = picture[Y][X];

    std::stack<std::array<int, 2>> toExploreStack;
    toExploreStack.push({X, Y});

    while (!toExploreStack.empty()) {
        std::array<int, 2> point = toExploreStack.top();
        toExploreStack.pop();
        int px = point[0];
        int py = point[1];
        bool execute = true;

        // plain for loop was slow, this method is fast
        if (exploredSet.count(point) == 1) {
            execute = false;
        }

        if (execute) {
            exploredSet.insert(point);

            if (px > 0 && picture[py][px - 1] == color) {
                toExploreStack.push({px - 1, py});
            }

            if (px < (W - 1) && picture[py][px + 1] == color) {
                toExploreStack.push({px + 1, py});
            }

            if (py > 0 && picture[py - 1][px] == color) {
                toExploreStack.push({px, py - 1});
            }

            if (py < (H - 1) && picture[py + 1][px] == color) {
                toExploreStack.push({px, py + 1});
            }
        }
    }

    for (std::array<int, 2> v : exploredSet) {
        std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Please help in optimizing Java solution. I have run out of ideas.

Already tried

- HashMap and sort it in end
- HashSet and sort it in the end.

Also it is surprising python in this case is able to finish faster than Java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` seems to have too much overhead in combination with the custom comparator. The `HashSet` version should work and is the same logic as the other versions. You just need to work with objects in order to have proper `hashCode`.
You could try changing the relevant lines to:

```
Set<List<Integer>> exploredSet = new HashSet<>();
...
if (exploredSet.contains(Arrays.asList(px, py))) {
...
exploredSet.add(Arrays.asList(px, py));
...
Comparator<List<Integer>> comp = Comparator.comparingInt((List<Integer> x) -> x.get(1)).thenComparingInt(x -> x.get(0));
exploredSet.stream()
        .sorted(comp)
        .map(v -> v.get(0) + " " + v.get(1))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**EDIT**

In general, if the Python solution is within the time limit an equivalent Java version with the same logic should be too. So why wasn't it?
"Proper HashCode" - that was exactly the problem with my solution...sorry, I was blind. Java has a very simple `hashCode` function. For a List of coordinates `X, Y` it's just `X + 31*Y`. So there are a lot of collisions. For `0 <= X, Y <= 999` there are just 31969 distinct hashCodes. That slows down the whole process. Using Strings should be faster and hopefully within the time limit:

```
Set<String> exploredSet = new HashSet<>();
...
if (exploredSet.contains(px + " " + py)) {
...
exploredSet.add(px + " " + py);
...
exploredSet.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> {
            String[] s = x.split(" ");
            return s[1] + " " + s[0]; }))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**EDIT2**

This is really weird. They probably pimped the python machine. Ok, one very last try with a boolean array `explored` instead of the Set `exploredSet`. That should be much faster, but it doesn't answer why the HashSet version is so slow.

```
boolean[] explored = new boolean[H*W]; // <- put this line after the 2 for-loops
...
if (explored[py*H+px]) {
...
explored[py*H+px] = true;
...
int index = 0;
for(int y=0; y<H; y++){
    for(int x=0; x<W; x++){
        if(explored[index]){
            System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hashset wont work as output has to be sorted in end. "The coordinates should also be ordered in the following way: sort first by the value y and then by the value x."

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot the sorting at the end. Edited the answer and added the sorting. Can you tell if that works?

Comment: Did not work still time limit exceeded.

Comment: Ok, that's my final attempt:-) Edited the answer.

Comment: Still timeout my friend. Agree it is challenging and I am also stubbed at python beating java in performance

Comment: Mabye you should find a competitive programmer to have a look at this. I added two tags "algorithm" and "hashset", maybe that will attract some. I added an alternative solution, but that doesn't answer why the hashset-version times out.